# How can I assign different characters to different keyboard shortcuts on Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac, language, shortcut-menu

I am using Macbook Air with OS 10.8.2. I bought my MAC from the US, and then moved to another country. Therefore, I had to change my keyboard language.

The problem is the keyboard layout is not the same.
For instance when I type:

Shift + 9 it is supposed to show '('. But instead it shows ')'

There are a lot of similar shortcuts.

What I want it when I type Shift + 9 on my keyboard, I want to show '(' which is the same character that is written on the physical keyboard.

I want to reassign characters to these shortcuts.

I tried a [software called Ukelele](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14495/ukelele), but could not get it to work well for me.

If you have used Ukelele before, please let me know how can I do it step by step.

Otherwise do you have any other solutions for me?

Comment: What language did you change your keyboard to?

Comment: PS and why did you need to change the keyboard exactly? Sometimes you can type the special characters needed for other languages very easily from the US layout and avoid all the mismatches with the printed keys.

Comment: @TomGewecke I don't know why it is important to know the language. Anyway I changed to Turkish. Because I need to use some turkish letter that don't exist in US keyboard.

Comment: I think you can type all those turkish letters while keeping all your normal shortcuts the same by using the US Extended Keyboard layout.  That would be an alternative to creating a custom layout via Ukelele.

Answer (score 1):

If the manual provided with Ukelele is not sufficient, you can ask for help with specific problems at the users group

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ukelele-users

It might be easier to just use the US Extended layout.  Shortcuts for Turkish special characters are

option c, then c  ç
option b, then g  ğ
option w, then i  ı
option u, then o  ö
option c, then s  ş
option u, then u  ü

PS Have you tried the Turkish Qwerty layout (instead of Turkish Qwerty PC) in system prefs/language & text/input sources?  It may also do what you need via the option keys while keeping the usual other shortcuts.

Comment: The problem is not letter. Problem is characters actually. I just want them to use them as they are on keyboard. When I change my keyboard to Turkih Qwerty PC letters are in difference position

Comment: @SNaRe Then why don't you use Turkish Qwerty instead of Turkish Qwerty PC as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Ukelele and Choose File > New Based on Current Input Source
2. Edit the layout and save it as a bundle to /Library/Keyboard Layouts/. Keyboard layouts in the user library aren't selected by default in password dialogs. The popovers shown when holding keys don't work with normal keylayout files.
3. Log out and back in
4. Enable the input source in System Preferences

Applying changes to a keylayout file requires logging out and back in after for example running `touch /Library/Keyboard Layouts/`.

You can disable the default layouts by removing them from `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox.*.plist` and logging out and back in.

Another option would be to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://superuser.com/questions/488364/change-section-key-to-less-than-in-os-x/490573#490573).