# How do I type the typeset "space" character?

Tags: keyboard

I've used the Keyboard Viewer a few times, and disappointingly have never seen the "space" character: `␣`

Is it possible to type this character directly via some combination of meta keys (option/shift)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to insert it using the default U.S. input source or other normal keyboard layouts:

```
$ grep -r '&#x2423;' /Volumes/Ukelele\ 2.2.4/System\ Keyboards/
$
```

Unicode Hex Input is the only keylayout that uses multipliers. If you use Unicode Hex Input, you can insert `␣` by typing 2423 while holding option.

Or create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://lri.me/keybindings.html):

```
{
    "~S" = (insertText:, "␣"); // option-shift-s
}
```

You could also [make a new keyboard layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72569/how-can-i-assign-different-characters-to-different-keyboard-shortcuts-on-mac/72900#72900) or [add characters to the press and hold popovers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion/44928#44928). I'm currently using an AppleScript (posted in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/498566/whats-the-easiest-way-to-insert-special-characters-on-os-x)) to insert special characters and plain text snippets.

Comment: This is really nice information. Since I'm bad at memorizing Unicode keycodes, and KeyBindings are unlikely to be synchronized, I implemented it into TextExpander, like I've already done that for ⌘ and ‽ and ∞. But this information is amazing. Thank you very much for it.